# H2DB mixed mode, client gets empty query

Tags: h2db

I'm trying to build some kind of Unit test for DB connection.
First I'm creating a new connection and new table , populate it and then check if the data exists, all good at this point.
than a client create a new connection and tries to get the same data but the query result is empty, 0 rows , 2 columns.

```
public class H2dbTest {

private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE TEST(ID varchar(12) primary key, NAME char(7))";
private static final String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO TEST(ID, NAME) VALUES (1234567,'TEST')";
private static final String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT ID, NAME FROM TEST";

public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeleteDbFiles.execute("~", "test", true);
        Connection connection = getDBConnection();
        insertWithStatement(connection);
        readFromClient();
}

private static void insertWithStatement(Connection connection) {
    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(CREATE_TABLE);
        stmt.execute(INSERT_QUERY);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SELECT_QUERY);
        System.out.println("Check DB after insert");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Id " + rs.getInt("ID") + " Name " + rs.getString("NAME"));
        }
        stmt.closeOnCompletion();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Message " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void readFromClient(){
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = getDBConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SELECT_QUERY);
        System.out.println("Client DB query result");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Id " + rs.getInt("ID") + " Name " + rs.getString("ID"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Message " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        connection.close();
    }
}
private static Connection getDBConnection() {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return dbConnection;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i was missing connection.commit();